# What is the significance of seeing Maa Ganga in dream?

Tags: goddess, ganga, dream

I had a dream of *Maa Ganga*. The thing is, I don't worship *Maa Ganga* or never have worshiped her before. Nor, I was thinking about *Maa Ganga* recently at any level i.e. in form of river, in form of goddess, or in form of spiritual divinity etc. I do worship *Mahadev* as in the form of Guru and complete authority over me. I had meaningful dreams before, in span of 20 years and they had amazing reality in real life. Not a made up reality, but with proof. I can't describe them here.

Anyways, here is the dream I had about *Maa Ganga*:

I saw a temple from inside, it was [old style house.](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6a/d8/28/6ad828f86caa318bd77dccb671db5504.jpg)

1. the Very first thing that I saw was a locked room and few humans inside (may be temple people, one was sitting filling register on [wooden old style box study table](https://www.riseonly.com/product_image/teak-wood-vintage-small-writing-desk1586.jpg) wearing Brahman cloths and others were cleaning or decorating). The room was amazingly clean as well as well-lit with *diyas* and had saffron-reddish walls. Inside that locked room, [wooden-steps-stand](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61NKg5IcGsL._SL1200_.jpg) which was placed far away from the entrance had the bright diamonds placed over it. They were like 4 or 5 (can't remember) with other few less bright diamonds placed in sequence of their brightness on different steps. Those were awesome diamonds they looked like a *diya* placed inside of diamond shaped glass cover, they were really bright and divine, but you can easily see them. Upon seeing them automatically your jaw drops and automatically you utter the sound "Ohhhhh!" They were so magnificent. There were 1 or 2 strangers like me, they looked as if they were here visiting temple with special permission.
2. Then I turned back towards *pujari* of the temple (nicely build body but had belly) at that time I was already crying due to excessive *bhakti* (I felt my heart at that point of time) and asked him that I want to do *darsana* of *Maa Ganga*. He pointed me towards an idol and said: go!
3. Idol was unusual than any other idol of *Maa Ganga*, huge may be 12 feet long of a mermaid lying on her belly in swimming posture-- made up of dusky color stone ([stone texture](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/e1/36/69/e13669bf943739baa2d55f41029141db.jpg) was like any other old temple idols). Upon seeing the idol I got "boodh" (knowledge of the idol and why it was created like that). Idol was in the form of mermaid (12 feet long) in mermaid swimming posture facing towards actual Ganga river which was flowing outside the temple. I literary felt that the invisible water was flowing around me in the temple and it was in huge force and thus I felt the knowledge that why the idol is facing in that direction? The idol was depicting the unidirectional juggernaut flow of *ganga* river.
4. But to my amazement, that idol moved her head with lot of efforts against the invisible current of water towards me, as if giving me blessing. Her face had a pleasant but serious smile and all the time (may be 5 secs) was fixed in same expression from the time it moved towards me to the time it took the original form of the idol as before.
5. After dream, I felt very nice and blessed.

What is the significance of seeing Maa Ganga in dream?